# Link opens twice the same window

Tags: href, new-window

I have next html code, to open a link into a new window:

```
<a rel="nueva_ventana" href="http://www.google.es">
</a>
```

When I click on it, it opens the same page twice, in two new windows.. which could be the problem?(I just want it to open once)
Thanks!

Comment: you might have some javascript getting all links with rel="nueva_ventana" and opening the href with the onclick event...
you should add 'return false;' to the end of that call so that the execution of the mouse click is cancelled

Comment: That could have been the problem, but I already have that 'return false'... and the onclick event is working properly with other links.. thank you anyway!

Comment: so what's the difference between the working links and the one above?
are there more click events listed in the javascript, maybe on parent items of the link?
could you post some samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, problem solved, I was importing twice my `commons.js`, where I was executing the `rel="nueva_ventana"`... so that it opened twice, thank you all!